# Drupal: List recently modified pages

Tags: drupal

In drupal, I would like to create a page like a site map, but also containing last modification date of each page and preferably mod author.

To clarify: I need to last date the page contents have changed, so this could be a change to the template or the underlying DB. Clearly, changing 1 DB entry can effect many pages.

Many thanks

Comment: Unless you're specifically keeping track of that exact data somewhere, you're not going to find it. Template files != Content, and Drupal doesn't keep a timestamp against every row in every table. You can use the node's 'modified' column for content, but for template files you're going to have examine the date of the physical files themselves and extract/merge that data manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last changed timestamp is stored in `node` table under `changed` column. You can get this information from here & display it in the teaser.

If you need more sophisticated change control then you need to enable node revisions: http://drupal.org/node/320614

Comment: Not exactly what I need since, since page can change (eg from database) without affetcing this column. However, this is useful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the views module, create a view for a sitemap and make an alias /sitemap or something similar.
When you add fields in the view, you can select: "Content: Updated date" as one of the fields.  Any time this content is changed, it will use that timestamp as the field.

I hope this answers the question.  If I misunderstand your question, I'll try to revise.